# How to rebase tokens using balance pallet?

Tags: balances

I want to reduce the balance of everyone say by 5% after say every 10 million blocks. It's not possible to loop over all balances, as that will be inefficient. AMPL solves it with using [Gons](https://medium.com/@marcilgen_70414/rebasing-tokens-with-oracles-and-liquidity-mining-the-ampleforth-approach-as-a-precursor-to-fdec8f83a0bb)

```
tokens= gonsBalance[account]/gonsPerToken
```

I am using [balance pallet](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/pallet_balances/index.html). What is the best way of doing using balance pallet? Will I have to fork it and modify it or it can be done by calling some functions in it.

Answer (score 2):

The balances pallet does not have a feature like this, nor do I think it should introduce this.

So yes, I think the best thing would be for you to write or fork your own solution for this kind of behavior.

Comment: It will be a good feature add that changes everyone's balances in the hook